# Search query on main table and foreign key related tables across all the columns with single criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables   like  `vehicles`  and `issues`.

table for `issues`

```
    CREATE TABLE issues
    (
        id                  uuid,
        issues_type                TEXT, 
        vehicle_id          uuid      NOT NULL REFERENCES vehicles (id),
    );
```

and for vehicle :

```
CREATE TABLE vehicles
(
    id                  uuid,
    license_plate       TEXT      NOT NULL,
);
```

**and I was doing a search query in issues table like this :**

```
    SELECT id, type , vehicle_id FROM issues
    WHERE CONTAINS((id, type ,vehicle_id ), 'query_string');
```

Now problem is I want to include **license_plate** from vehicle table in search query as well in search result in single query.

**EDIT**
Expected output is like :

just want issue table data in result . just want to include  licence_plate in search (vehicle  is referenced via id to issue table but user can search  licence_plate  as well)

Comment: There is no `contains()` function in Postgres

Comment: It would help if you add a data sample and exact expected result. It smells like a `join` btw ;)

Comment: @JimJones  can you please check ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I am just testing on sqlfeddile. my mistake

Comment: @pie nice. where is the data sample?

Comment: @JimJones sir as I mentioned , I just need data of issues table . like only issue table data . just want that if in search I am getting  `license_plate`  it should still search for  issues which have id of vehicle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple `inner join` for it:

```
select 
t1.* 
from issues t1 
inner join vehicles t2 on t1.vehicle_id=t2.id
where 
t1.id= ' your id'  -- put your value
or t1.issues_type ilike '%yourtype%' -- put the type
or t2.license_plate ilike '%numplate%' -- put the number plate
```

Above query will give the result if any of the value from `id`, `type` or `licence_plate` will match. if you want to match all the criteria then just change `or` to `and`.

EDIT:

if you want to search across all the field with single criteria use below query:

```
select * from (
select 
t1.*, t2.license_plate
from issues t1 
inner join vehicles t2 on t1.vehicle_id=t2.id
) tab
where tab::text ilike '%criteria%' -- write your criteria here. it will search across all the fields
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=dc2114a15c0ecdfa5dfcd24f0ca799c2)

Comment: just a minor issue here. Like in future I have 15 fields in issue tab . then I want to make this generic . not just limited to these 3 .  and for vehicle it will only include license_plate.

Comment: `t1.*` will include all the columns from table `issues` always. if you want to get the `license_plate` also in field list. just use `select t1.*, t2.licence_plate from .......`. but if you want add search condition then you have to change it manually. further if you want every thing generic then you have to use dynamic query. Also ask separate question for this requirement.

Comment: got it . but my search_string would be single . like don't know either its id , type of  license_plate or whatever . I just need to check if either of these filed matches , I need to  show those issues

Comment: Updated the answer for you additional requirement.